# SQL multi-sorting database similar to excel

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

First of all I'm using MYSQL.

My database has three tables: rows, columns, cells. Rows contains only id, columns id and name but cells is crucial. It looks like this:

```
id | rowId | columnId | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |     1 |        1 |     v1 |     v2 |     v3 |     v4 |     v5 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 2 |     1 |        2 |     v5 |     v6 |     v7 |     v8 |     v9 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 |     2 |        1 |    v10 |    v12 |    v13 |    v14 |    v15 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 4 |     2 |        2 |     v1 |     v2 |     v3 |     v4 |     v5 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 5 |     3 |        1 |     v5 |     v6 |     v7 |     v8 |     v9 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 6 |     3 |        2 |    v10 |    v12 |    v13 |    v14 |    v15 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It represents table with 6 cells (2 columns and 3 rows) each contains 5 values.
What I would like to do is get list of rows ids sorted by multiple tables containing certain values.

Example sort:
value1=v10 and columndId=1,
value4=v8 and columndId=2,
and rest in any order

Output:

```
id | rowId | columnId | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 |     2 |        1 |    v10 |    v12 |    v13 |    v14 |    v15 |
 2 |     1 |        2 |     v5 |     v6 |     v7 |     v8 |     v9 |
 6 |     3 |        2 |    v10 |    v12 |    v13 |    v14 |    v15 |
```

so right rows order is 2 -> 1 -> 3

What I got to is this SQL query:

```
SELECT rowId FROM cells WHERE
    columnId = 1 OR
    columnId = 2 OR
ORDER BY value1 = v10, value4 = v8;
```

but it gives me this output:

```
id | rowId | columnId | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 3 |     2 |        1 |    v10 |    v12 |    v13 |    v14 |    v15 |
 6 |     3 |        2 |    v10 |    v12 |    v13 |    v14 |    v15 |
 2 |     1 |        2 |     v5 |     v6 |     v7 |     v8 |     v9 |
 5 |     3 |        1 |     v5 |     v6 |     v7 |     v8 |     v9 |
 1 |     1 |        1 |     v1 |     v2 |     v3 |     v4 |     v5 |
 4 |     2 |        2 |     v1 |     v2 |     v3 |     v4 |     v5 |
```

Do You have any ides how to handle that kind of sorting?

Answer (score 0):

hey you can do a case order by

so

```
order by case when value1=v10 then 1
              when value14=v8 then 2
              when something=v2 then 3
         end
```

this will order it by the number values cooresponding to your case statements, so you can creatively order anything you want